# Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org when trying to do something with the remote branch

Tags: git, networking, bitbucket

Every time I try to do something in the remote like git push origin master or git remote show origin for a project in bitbucket, it gives me`fatal: unable to access 'https://remote_url_provided_by_bitbucket.git/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org`
What could be the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use same https url from your browser ? Please check your local firewall ?

address should be as below, 
https://user_name@bitbucket.org/user_name/repository_name and same should be returned by command  `git remote get-url remote_name`